# How to identify where a resource is being used?

Tags: c#, winforms

**Background:**
I recently updated my WinForms app from .NET 1.1 to .NET 4.0 and as part of that I also gave it a bit of a facelift.

Previously I was dynamically loading .ico files that had been embedded into the main app .exe into 3 image list components (small, medium, large) that sit on the apps main form.

All the .ico files lived in an /Images folder of the project. However part of the facelift replaced all these files with prettier .png files of the appropriate sizes. I have now added them directly into the 3 image list components and so they exist in the /Images folder for reference.

**Problem:** I've come to clear up the project and have SVN deleted the .ico files from the /Images folder however when I come to build the project it fails with the error: "error reading resource file '[full path to the project]\Images\lookupAdd_32.ico' - the system cannot find the file specified"

If I SVN revert the deletion then it builds and runs fine again. If I search the entire solution for lookupAdd_32.ico it finds nothing so I'm at a bit of a loss at how to identify where the hell it's being used. Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: Look in the resx. Not sure if those are searched

Comment: Yes @dkackman is right, Try edit resx file which may refer the path of `ico` still. If not then just search for `lookupAdd_32.ico` in entire solution.

Comment: Thanks I'm not in a position to look for this right now but will check soon. @Sriram - as indicated in the question I already have searched the entire solution and Visual Studio finds nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that unlike other .ico files that were excluded from the /Images folder in the solution Visual Studio did not seem to clear up correctly.

All my .ico's were configured to be embedded resources and a  tag had been left in the csproj file. So having SVN reverted the deletion and included it in the project again I:

- set the ico's build action to none
- excluded it from the project
- cleaned solution
- SVN deleted the file, presto it now compiles without issue, yay!